# Justify vertical li element text with css

Tags: html, css

I'd like to be able to just justify this text..

For the life of me I cannot get it to work.

```
HTML:
<div id="main-content-left-container">
<ul id="left-bullets">
        <li>I want all/li>
        <li>of this text</li>
    <li>justified to the left-bullets 70% width size</li>
</ul>
<img > //not important here
</div>

CSS:
#main-content-left-container {
width: 450px;
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-left: 5px;
}

#left-bullets {
position: relative;
width: 70%;
margin: 0 15px 0 auto;
list-style-type: disc;
font-size: 12pt;
text-align: justify;
}
```

I have tried many variations and combinations of text-align in the CSS. Display: Block, etc. Yet I still cannot get this text to justify.

Comment: Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/r8Dts/1/ It is justified.

Comment: I would like it justified across the width. As in there is more space between some words to make them extend the width of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [found](http://webdesign.about.com/b/2008/03/21/reader-question-how-to-justify-a-1-line-headline.htm#comment-266508) this piece of code that could do it:

```
#element:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This is not supported by some versions of IE though.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/LtKeK/